# Can I create a new comment type?

Tags: comments

I want to add different custom fields to comments that belongs to different user group, and display different types  of comments in different ways. But WP has some default comment types that shows the type column probably is not for this job. Would anybody make this clear for me?

Comment: Read  - [Custom Comment type, maybe ?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14223/custom-comment-type-maybe)

Comment: They suggested using custom post types instead. But didn't point if it is legal to create a new comment type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a quick look at [`comments.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/comment.php#L0), I can say - using custom comment type is so far legal, however I didn't played with this yet but you can, and post back with your results if you found any illegal stuff in this.

I found on codex the [`get_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) function is accepting `comment type` as argument, so you'll not be having any problems with accessing comments of type `foo`.

Also other functions are looking clean to use with custom `comment type`.

<sup>*Note - Take necessary precautions ( BackUp ) before doing any changes to live site !*</sup>